# issue with window.onload in included file

Tags: javascript

I have a php page that runs standalone without any issue. 
When I open the page it includes a js file with some functions. What I am interested in is that the JS contains a

```
window.onload = function() {
    //my js stuffs here
}
```

that fires when the php opens.

Next step was to move the php inside my framework loading it in a div of an existing page. 
So in the framework I did

```
$('#destinatario').change(function(){
    var hk = $(this).val();
    $('#sotto').html('');
    $('#sotto').load('../websocket/index.php?hk='+hk);
});
```

my page keeps loading fine without any inconvenient but the window.onload never gets fired. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The page is already loaded, therefore onload has already fired by the time you installed it. Remove the window.onload around your code

Comment: yes I know. But I'd like to keep it so I'll use @peterpeterson workaround

Comment: Just sayin, why would you keep it?

Comment: just to be sure it fires before the user can do anything else. JS is not my cup of tea ;)

Comment: It's not about JS, it's just logic, you are adding an event listener to `window.onload` but you are not using it as a listener, you are calling it like a regular function, that's unnecessary clutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could workaround this doing:

```
$('#destinatario').change(function(){
    var hk = $(this).val();
    $('#sotto').html('');
    $('#sotto').load('../websocket/index.php?hk='+hk, function (){
       window.onload();

    });
});
```

if it does not work create a function on index.php something like loaded() and then in the callback to when the index.php is loaded call that function.

Comment: thanks. The idea of a callback on the load function is smart enough and it works!

Comment: Why not just call the code directly? Don't workaround if you can fix the root problem

Comment: I need to be sure the code inside that .onload event has run before the user can do anything else